# Status 500 error while committing changes to Solr index

Tags: solr

I have added files to our Solr index with a curl command:

```
curl http://<servername>:8983/solr/<collection>/update -H \"Content-Type: text/xml\" --data-binary 1.xml
```

This ran fine and added the files.

On the Solr UI, in the statistics section for the collection, the "Current" symbol has changed from a green tick to a red circle (indicating there are uncommitted changes).

I'm now trying to commit the changes using the curl:

```
curl http://<servername>:8983/solr/<collection>/update?commit=true
```

However this produces the following error response:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":6},
  "error":{
    "msg":"/opt/solr/solr_dir/solr-8.8.0/server/solr/inc_tickets/data/index/_qz.fdt",
    "trace":"java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/solr/solr_dir/solr-8.8.0/server/solr/inc_tickets/data/index/_qz.fdt\n\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)\n\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)\n\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)\n\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177)\n\tat java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)\n\tat java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.fsync(IOUtils.java:469)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fsync(FSDirectory.java:331)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.sync(FSDirectory.java:286)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.sync(NRTCachingDirectory.java:158)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.store.LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.sync(LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.startCommit(IndexWriter.java:5103)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3461)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3771)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commit(IndexWriter.java:3729)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:675)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessorFactory$RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1082)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1069)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processCommit(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:169)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerUtils.handleCommit(RequestHandlerUtils.java:69)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:76)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:216)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2646)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:794)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:567)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:357)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1612)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1582)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n",
    "code":500}}
```

Comment: The user that Solr is running under doesn't have access to the `/opt/solr/solr_dir/...` directory. Give it access or change the owning user for the directory where the index is stored (and the configuration if you want to update it through the API).

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh, this was the problem. To fix it, I started the Solr server with a designated user, and made sure that the folder structure Solr is in is owned by this user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user that Solr is running under doesn't have access to the `/opt/solr/solr_dir/...` directory.

Give it access or change the owning user for the directory where the index is stored (and the configuration if you want to update it through the API).

You can use `chmod` to change access rights to a directory or `chown <user>.<group>` to change who the owner of the directory is. If you include `-R` it will change the property for the whole hierarchy.